# Solution to Keep gh-pages up to day with a master/main branch

Tags: reactjs, github, visual-studio-code, npm, github-pages

I recently build a `gh-pages` using React and found that my changes in the main branches would not be synced with `gh-pages`.

Then I found that I don't need to push the whole updates to `gh-pages` and even to `master/main branch` for updating my site. In order to see updates on my git page, I ran `npm run deploy` using Vscode on the main branch then just wait for a few minutes to see updates on my `gh-pages.`"
Simple Solution: enter `npm run deploy` on the `master/main branch` then wait a few minutes to see updates showing on your `gh-pages` and your site on `github pages`

Below is a suggested solution but it's not working for me.

```
`$ git add .`
```

`$ git status // to see what changes are going to be commited`

`$ git commit -m 'Some descriptive commit message'`

`$ git push origin master`

`$ git checkout gh-pages // go to the gh-pages branch`

`$ git rebase master // bring gh-pages up to date with master`

`$ git push origin gh-pages // commit the changes`

`$ git checkout master // return to the master branch`

Hope this post can help. Thank you.

Resolve the syncing issue between `gh-pages` and `master/main branch` in `GitHub`. This issue refers to the updates made in `master/main branch` are not synced to `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution: enter `npm run deploy` on the `master/main branch` then wait a few minutes to see updates showing on your `gh-pages` and your site on `github pages`